# Minimum element of contraction subset?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. A function $f:X\to X$ is a contraction if it satisfies $d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y)$ for all $x\neq y \in X$.

EDITED: Assume $X$ is compact.

I have proven that the function $\Phi:X\to \mathbb R$ given by $\Phi(x)=d(x,f(x))$ is continuous.

How do I deduce that the image $\Phi(X)\subseteq \mathbb R$ has a minimum element?

Any help/step-by-step solutions appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think it is true?

Comment: You mean the continuity of $\Phi(x)$?

Comment: No, I mean why do you think it is true that $\Phi(X)$ has a minimum element? But after your edit, I think it should be immediately clear.

Comment: Is it because since it is compact, it is bounded, so must be bounded below?

Comment: Do you know the Extreme Value Theorem of calculus, and its relation to compactness?

Comment: Ah I see, so since the continuous image of a compact set is also compact (and therefore bounded and closed) the extreme value theorem applies, meaning that by definition the function $\Phi$ must obtain a maximum and minimum at least once?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

The existence of a minimal $x$ is not true in general.  Consider $X=\mathbb{R}$ and the function $f: X \to X$ via $f(x) = 1+ x- \tanh(x)$.  Then $f'(x) = 1-1/\cosh^2(x) \in [0,1)$, and from this and the MVT we can show that $\vert f(x) - f(y) \vert < \vert x-y\vert$ for all $x,y$.  However, $\vert f(x)-x\vert = \vert \tanh(x)-1\vert = 1-\tanh(x)$, and the infimum of this is never achieved.

You can prove what you want if you assume in addition that $X$ is compact.

Comment: $X$ is compact, apologies, I've made an edit to the post!

Comment: Do you know what properties the continuous image of a compact set must have?